# Assign values through VB Scripts For Automation

Tags: vbscript, automation, testcomplete

Im new to Automation, Test Complete Tool, and VB Scripts. I've been given a task to automate a Webpage. I have stuck in Login Page. I have a Username and Password TextBoxex. How can I assign the textbox values through my vb scripts. Please help me with this. I have given the scripts that I've given which is not working.

```
      Call Sys.Process("iexplore").Window("#32770", "Connect to 172.16.1.88", 1).Window("SysCredential", "", 1).Window("ComboBoxEx32", "", 1).Window("ComboBox", "", 1).Window("Edit", "", 1).SetText("username")
      BuiltIn.Delay(1000)

      Call Aliases.iexplore.dlgConnectTo17216188.SysCredential.ComboBoxEx32.ComboBox.Edit.Keys("[Tab]")

      Call Sys.Process("iexplore").Window("#32770", "Connect to 172.16.1.88", 1).Window("SysCredential", "", 1).Window("Edit", "", 1).SetText("pasword")

      BuiltIn.delay(10000)

      Call Sys.Process("iexplore").Window("#32770", "Connect to 172.16.1.88", 1).Window("Button", "OK", 1).Click()
```

The error thrown is

```
"Unable to find the object SetText("username")

"Unable to find the object SetText("pasword")"
```

Please help me to clear this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You'll likely have better luck asking this on the [TestComplete forums](http://smartbear.com/forums/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got an answer in the TestComplete Forum?

If you did not, then try using the Keys method instead of SetText - the SetText method is not supported in TestComplete 7, and if you are using this version, this will not work.

You can also try assigning the text through wText:
EditControl.wText = "username"

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got the answer for this question through SmartBear TestComplete Forum. Thanks for referring the site.,

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Remove "Call" Keyword before your Captured Object, as generally "Call "is used to invoke specific Subroutine or Function and you are using "Call" for accessing UI component which will never work.
2. Simply use  "delay(10000)" it also works to delay your script for specific time.

Let us know your further result on this.

Thanks,